# Idea terminal cannot open Electron.exe by command(npm run electron:serve)

Tags: vuejs2, electron

I use command in idea terminal
e.g.npm run electron:serve

My code environment：

- Mac M1/macos Ventura13.0.1
- node@14.21.2
- npm@6.14.17
- electron@12.2.3

The command stopped after Vue project compiled successful.
like this:

[image]

I try to run command `rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json&&npm install`
but cannot fix the situation.

Colleague's code environment：

- win10
- node@16.17.1
- npm@8.19.2
- electron@9.4.4

The normal situation in my colleague's computer:

[image]

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "RetinaCare",
  "version": "2.3.11",
  "publishDate": "2022-03-07",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "electron:build": "vue-cli-service electron:build",
    "electron:serve": "vue-cli-service electron:serve",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps"
  },
  "main": "background.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "chokidar": "^3.4.2",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "el-table-infinite-scroll": "^1.0.10",
    "electron-builder": "^23.6.0",
    "electron-updater": "^4.3.9",
    "element-ui": "^2.13.2",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-rc.7",
    "iconv-lite": "^0.6.3",
    "js-md5": "^0.7.3",
    "jspdf-html2canvas": "^1.4.9",
    "print-js": "^1.2.0",
    "qiao-is-online": "0.0.6",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-html-to-paper": "^1.3.1",
    "vue-image-zoomer": "1.0.4",
    "vue-print-nb": "^1.5.0",
    "vue-qr": "^2.4.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.2.0",
    "vuex": "^3.4.0",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-standard": "^5.1.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "electron": "^12.2.3",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.2",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "lint-staged": "^9.5.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder": "~2.0.0-rc.4",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "gitHooks": {
    "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,jsx,vue}": [
      "vue-cli-service lint",
      "git add"
    ]
  }
}
```

This is my vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  pages: {
    index: 'src/main.js',
    login: 'src/login/main.js'
  },
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.resolve.symlinks(true)
  },
  devServer: {
    hot: true,
    hotOnly: true,
    watchContentBase: false
  },
  configureWebpack: {
    target: 'electron-renderer',
    externals: ['fsevents']
  },
  pluginOptions: {
    electronBuilder: {
      extraResources: {
        from: './public/dll',
        to: './dll'
      },
      builderOptions: {
        asar: false,
        mac: {
          target: {
            target: 'default',
            arch: [
              'x64',
              'arm64'
            ]
          }
        },
        win: {
          requestedExecutionLevel: 'requireAdministrator',
          icon: './public/ljj_256.ico', 
          artifactName: '${productName}-Setup-${version}.${ext}', 
          target: [
            {
              target: 'nsis', 
              arch: [
                'ia32'
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        productName: 'testProject', 
        nsis: {
          include: './public/nsis/installer.nsh',
          perMachine: false, 
          runAfterFinish: true,
          oneClick: false, 
          allowElevation: true,
          allowToChangeInstallationDirectory: true, 
          installerIcon: './public/ljj_256.ico', 
          uninstallerIcon: './public/ljj_256.ico', 
          installerHeaderIcon: './public/ljj_256.ico', 
          createDesktopShortcut: true, 
          createStartMenuShortcut: true, 
          shortcutName: 'electronProject', 
          deleteAppDataOnUninstall: true
        },
        publish: [
          {
            provider: 'generic',
            url: 'https://www.electronProject_test.com/client'
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is project catalogue:

[image]

Because mac m1's framework is arm64,i changed electron version from ^9.2.0 to ^12.2.3, added electron-builder ^23.6.0 to package.json.
By the way i started sample project of vue-electron successful on the Mac.The question is so strange

Comment: Please share the scripts in your `package.json`

Comment: And if you use `wait-on`, please add the flag `-v` after it to enable debug logs and share the error you get.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for answered my question. Package.json has just been added to the issue.I think the `wait-on` dependence not used in project.I cannot found this dependence in whole project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by delete yarn.lock in project. Beacuse of yarn.lock in my project, so vue-cli will  look for yarn runtime environment  in server. But i have not install yarn runtime environment on server. The code stop at `hasProjectYarn(api.getCwd())`. If you dont need yarn, Meanwhile yarn.lock file in your project ,you should delete the file!